# Detecting end of VOD stream with OSMF?

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, osmf, akamai

I have the event listener:

```
mediaPlayerSprite.mediaPlayer.addEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE, playerStateChange);
```

But this doesn't seem to give any indicator that the stream has ended... i.e. according to:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/media/MediaPlayerState.html

There is no event for Stream Ended... so how do you detect this reliably?

In case it's relevant, I am using the Akamai Advanced Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it... it's TimeEvent.COMPLETE :)